# Vim: Color a line, keep it colored until line no longer visible

Tags: vim

In Vim, I want to be able to press a key to color/highlight/mark the current line, and KEEP it colored until either the line is no longer visible on the screen, or I press the key again to toggle highlight.  How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: I did some brief searching and at least found a way to highlight the current line.  This is the type of question where it seems like simply asking early on would make the most sense.

I am relatively unknowledgeable about vim, and for these types of things, the solution could be so broad, that it seems best to ask and learn by example.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution consists of the following steps:

1. Create a highlight group for deleting previously highlighted text, for example:

   ```
   highlight  UIgnore ctermbg=white guibg=bg
   ```

   where you will need to change `white` with your default color terminal background (ctermbg).
2. Create the following commands:

   ```
   command! -nargs=0 H :call matchadd("Constant",getline('.'))
   command! -nargs=0 D :call matchadd("UIgnore",getline('.'))
   ```

   Here you can use `"Constant"` or any other group name (see `:help group`).

Now you can highlight any given line with the command `:H` and remove the highlight with `:D`. A caveat with this approach is that adding or removing text from highlighted lines will remove the highlight. So you will need to do `:H` again.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `~/.vimrc` to highlight cursorline in green

```
"cursorline and it's highlighting
set cursorline
hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=green
```